# Swap point colors in shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a shiny app that displays a plot with ggplot. I want to make a pulldown that lets users switch between two color schemes for the points. ui:

```
pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel('PCA'),
    sidebarPanel(
       selectInput('colorBy', 'Color By', c('red', 'blue'))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('plot1')
    )
 )
```

Server code (including some pseudocode):

```
function(input, output, session) {

  # create new columns with alternate color schemes
  iris$red = rep('red', (dim(iris)[1]))
  iris$blue = rep('blue', (dim(iris)[1]))

  #FIXME  
  # set the color scheme 
  colorScheme <- reactive({
    if (input$colorBy == 'red'){
      iris$red
    }

    else{
      iris$blue
    }
  })

 # make the plot
 output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
   ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +     geom_point(colour=colorScheme)
  })

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `colorScheme` is a function so you should add `()` at the end

```
 output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
            ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point(colour=colorScheme())
    })
```